# jenkins pipeline example for creating a folder with a description

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I can do this manually in the console with a job dsl step, but can't figure out how to accomplish from a pipeline - declarative or scripted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want  to create a directory, then you can use `mkdir`.

```
pipeline {
agent any 
stages 
    {
     stage ("stage 1"){
          steps
            {
               script {
                 bat returnStatus: true, script:"mkdir Myfolder"
                 //   OR
                 sh "mkdir -p myfolder"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry didn't get back on this. No, this was not what I was looking for. Was looking for way to create a Jenkins folder. I ended up writing a /vars script using com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.* along with jenkins.model.Jenkins - which worked

Answer (score 0):

['folder'](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/Job-DSL-Commands.md#folder) is like ['job'](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/Job-DSL-Commands.md#job) and can take `description` and `displayName` if you choose

```
folder('myFolder'){
    description('my description')
    displayName('My Display Name')
}
```

If the question is, `How can i add a folder using a Jenkins pipeline script (Jenkinsfile)`? You will likely want to look at your 'Snippet Generator' `http://<your-jenkins-instance:8080>/pipeline-syntax/` and look at the 'jobDsl' Sample Step. Generated code from the Snippet Generator will look like this.

```
jobDsl scriptText: '''folder(\'myFolder\'){
    description(\'my description\')
    displayName(\'My Display Name\')
}'''
```

And your Pipeline script would look like

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Add Folder') {
            steps {
                jobDsl scriptText: """folder('myFolder'){
    description('my description')
    displayName('My Display Name')
}"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```